# Web service to move items to the recycle bin

Tags: 2013, web-services, recycle-bin

Running SP 2013, I am looking for a web servcie that moves items to the recycle bin rather than deleting them permanently.

Something like: [SPListItem.Recycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms442702?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396%20for) for web services.

Any hint?